# After updating to rails 5 spec fails with ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am updating rails to 5.0.1 and got a failing spec

This spec is the

```
describe "POST create", :vcr do
    let(:subscription) { mock_model(Subscription).as_null_object }
    before do
      allow(Subscription).to receive(:new).and_return(subscription)
    end

    it "creates a new Subscription" do
      expect(Subscription).to receive(:new).
        with("card_expiration" => "a quick brown fox").
        and_return(subscription)
      post :create, params: { :subscription => { "card_expiration" => "a quick brown fox" }}
    end
end
```

It fails with

```
Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[{"card_expiration"=>"a quick brown fox"}]
       +[<ActionController::Parameters {"card_expiration"=>"a quick brown fox"} permitted: true>]
```

How can I get the ActionController::Parameters into the expectation?

Comment: Based on the title of your test, maybe you could just test to see if the parameters go through. If you can verify that the subscription gets made, it guarantees the parameters went through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the expectation to expect an actual ActionController::Parameters object, like so:

```
 parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(
        "card_expiration" => "a quick brown fox").permit!

 expect(Subscription).to receive(:new).
        with(parameters).
        and_return(subscription)
```